# I am getting error when trying to use Reachablitiy

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I want to alert user if they don't have Internet connection in my xcode swift app, so I am using Reachablity to do this. But when I implement my code into Viewcontroller I am getting this error:

> Expected Declaration

I have tried to put my code into `viewdidload` also but not worked.

This is the code:

```
 if Reachability.checkIntenetRechable() == false {
    let alertView = UIAlertCole: "APP_NAME", message: "Please check your internet connection.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    //alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction ) in }))
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction ) in
    // Put some code for okay button
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: Image With Error]

Comment: We have add checkIntenetRechable() method in Reachability.swift file.

Comment: @mr-bista Looks like our edits collided or something, yours as invalidated mine and has put back typos and capitalization errors. :/ (fixed)

Comment: Did you add this checkIntenetRechable() in Reachability file  ? If not then add as per my post

Answer (score 0):

You may mistype the method.
I see it has two typos.

Didn't you mean this?

```
if Reachability.checkInternetReachable() == false { /* */ }
```

Expected declaration means that the **method your are calling does not exist**.

Comment: If you think OP's issue is a simple typo, you should flag/vote to close the question as "typo or cannot reproduce". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the method doesn't exist in Reachability file SO Add this method in Reachability file

```
class func checkIntenetRechable() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
    }
```